# CSS, and jQuery Navigation Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, navigation

I am having some serius trouble wrapping my head around this one.  The issue occurs with the desktop navigation of this website, only in safari on desktop or laptop, and only on certain pages....

Fully Working On Safari: [About Page](http://dynamicartisans.com/about.html)

Partially Working On Safari: [Index](http://dynamicartisans.com) and [Philosophy](http://dynamicartisans.com/marketing-philosophy.html)

Once again, the issue only seems to occur in Safari on Windows, Mac Desktop and Mac Laptop. If I delete the video background on the index it solves the problem in my testing on the Index page, however: the philosophy page does not have a video gackground and the Navigation "freezes".  It gets stuck on a hover state and does not respond to mouse events afterwards, while the rest of the page is still functional.

If any mac users out there care to peek at the code with Dev Tools I would appreciate it! I'm completely out of options... At a total loss.

Comment: I should add that on the index page in dev / inspect tools, when I delete the video background layer the navigation works perfectly in safari on desktop and laptop.  On the philosophy page it does not have a video background or even the same div layer that was used to display video on the index.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your header position absolute? Maybe for some reason the background has a higher specificity when clicked...

Comment: with no success... It only occurs in Safari 5 as far as I can tell now.